# Moving Sheet order in Excel with apache POI; how to avoid changing formulas

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Im trying to move a sheet in my excel between other sheets with Apache POI.
to accomplish that Im calling

```
workbook.setSheetOrder("sheetToMove", 1);
```

problem is in another sheet i have formulas like "=sheetToMove!A2"
if I do above call, the formula changes to "=unrelatedSheet!A2"

my current workaround involves going through all cells of the referencing sheet, storing away all the formulas + row/column information in a datastructure before changing sheet orders. after I changed the order, I go thorugh the stored formulas and put them in the correct cell. Is there a more efficient way of changing sheet order without changing the formulas?

Comment: I can't find setSheetOrder as a Method for workbook in Excel VBA. Is this a routine you have written yourself? If so, you may need to show the code to solve the problem.

Comment: im not using excel vba. i am using java / apache poi (see tags) updating question to make it more clear

Comment: Ok, sorry. I can't help then.